# clflush not giving correct answer in i7 for const data type

Tags: c++, c, linux, performance-testing, cpu-architecture

I have written two programs to check whether clflush is evicting my data from cache or not. Out of two program I have written , only one is giving correct result ( as per my expectation , after clflush, access time must be higher than before flush).

Here is my Program1 where I am getting expected result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

inline void clflush(volatile void *p)
{
    asm volatile ("clflush (%0)" :: "r"(p));
}

inline uint64_t rdtsc()
{
    unsigned long a, d;
    asm volatile ("cpuid; rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "ebx", "ecx"); 
    return a | ((uint64_t)d << 32);
}


static int i=10; // static variable 

inline void test()
{
    uint64_t start, end;    
    int j;    
    start = rdtsc();
    j = i;
    end = rdtsc();
    printf("took %lu ticks\n", end - start);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    test();
    test();
    printf("flush: ");
    clflush((void *)&i);
    test();
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output ( as expected)

```
took 314 ticks
took 282 ticks
flush: took 442 ticks
took 272 ticks
```

Here is another program , where **I am not getting expected result.**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdint.h>

inline void clflush(volatile void *p)
{
    asm volatile ("clflush (%0)" :: "r"(p));
}

inline uint64_t rdtsc()
{
    unsigned long a, d;
    asm volatile ("cpuid; rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "ebx", "ecx"); 
    return a | ((uint64_t)d << 32);
}


static const int i=10; // I make this as constant 

inline void test()
{
    uint64_t start, end;    
    int j;    
    start = rdtsc();
    j = i;
    end = rdtsc();
    printf("took %lu ticks\n", end - start);
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    test();
    test();
    printf("flush: ");
    clflush((void *)&i);
    test();
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my output ( as expected)

```
took 314 ticks
took 282 ticks
flush: took 282 ticks // same as previous
took 272 ticks


--------
took 314 ticks
took 282 ticks
flush: took 272 ticks // lower than previous
took 272 ticks
```

If I make  static int i=10; into  static const int i=10; then the result is not as per my expectation. I am getting lower value/equal access time after  clflush.

Can anyone explain why this is happening ? How can I make it (either in C or C++) as per my expectation ( higher access time after clflush as program1) ?

I am using GCC under Fedora19 linux. Any help will be highly appreciated .

Comment: What compiler options are you using?

Comment: I am compiling with this option, gcc -O0 test.c -o test

Comment: How long does it take if you remove the `j=i` completely? I'm guessing you just measure the latency of `cpuid`

Comment: @ Leeor , if I remove j=i statement completely , I got took 296 ticks
took 272 ticks
flush: took 272 ticks
took 272 ticks for both case ( non-const and const ).

Comment: (Keep the `@` attached to the name, otherwise SO won't send a message about your comment). Anyway this shows that the bulk of the time measure is indeed the cpuid (and the stall its serialization induces)

Comment: Related: [clflush to invalidate cache line via C function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51830976) has a fairly accurate measurement of cache hit vs. miss that tries to account for `lfence + rdtsc` overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem here is that CPUID + RDTSC is far too long, compared to the "instructions between".

I get very varying results, presumably depending on "luck" of which actual CPU the code ends up running on, what the other CPU's are doing, etc, etc.

Here's three runs in a row of the second program:

```
took 92 ticks
took 75 ticks
flush: took 75 ticks
took 474 ticks

took 221 ticks
took 243 ticks
flush: took 221 ticks
took 242 ticks

took 221 ticks
took 221 ticks
flush: took 221 ticks
took 230 ticks
```

However, I don't think we can draw the conclusion that "clflush doesn't work" from this. Just that there's enough clockcycles and enough out of order execution in the processor to overcome the cache-flush and re-load the data.

You would probably get a much more noticeable effect if you have a large chunk of data, say a few kilobytes. I'll make some experiments in a bit, but right now I need some food...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

inline void clflush(volatile void *p)
{
    __asm volatile ("clflush (%0)" :: "r"(p));
}

inline uint64_t rdtsc()
{
    unsigned long a, d;
    __asm volatile ("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : : "ebx", "ecx"); 
    return a | ((uint64_t)d << 32);
}


static int v[1024]; 
uint64_t   t[5];
int        r[5];
int        ti = 0;

static inline void test()
{
    uint64_t start, end;    
    int j;    
    start = rdtsc();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
    j += v[i];
    }
    end = rdtsc();
    r[ti] = j;
    t[ti++] = end - start;
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)
    {
    v[i] = i;
    }
    test();
    test();
    t[ti++] = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1024; i+=4)
    {
    clflush((void *)&v[i]);
    }
    test();
    test();
    for(int i = 0; i < ti; i++)
    {
    if (t[i] == 0)
    {
        printf("flush\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Test %lu [res=%d]\n", t[i], r[i]);
    }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I moved the printf out of the test-path, to reduce the amount of time spent there, and made the flushed region much larger. This gives a much longer runtime, which certainly helps the measurements.

```
Test 2538 [res=523776]
Test 2593 [res=523776]
flush
Test 4845 [res=523776]
Test 2592 [res=523776]

Test 2550 [res=523776]
Test 2771 [res=523776]
flush
Test 4782 [res=523776]
Test 2513 [res=523776]

Test 2550 [res=523776]
Test 2708 [res=523776]
flush
Test 4356 [res=523776]
Test 2593 [res=523776]
```

As you can see, after the flush, the data is about twice the time to fetch compared to the first access.

Edit:

Using const, like this

```
static const int v[1024] = 
{
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    /* snip 62 lines equal to this */
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
};
```

gives this result:

```
Test 14139 [res=8704]
Test 2639 [res=8704]
flush
Test 5287 [res=8704]
Test 2597 [res=8704]

Test 12983 [res=8704]
Test 2652 [res=8704]
flush
Test 4859 [res=8704]
Test 2550 [res=8704]

Test 12911 [res=8704]
Test 2581 [res=8704]
flush
Test 4705 [res=8704]
Test 2649 [res=8704]
```

As you can see, the third access is clearly slower than than the second and the fourth. The first access is slower because there is nothing in the cache at all at the first access (including page-tables, etc).

Comment: thanks @ Mats for answering. To prevent out of order execution I am using CPUID here. Another point, I also tried with static const int arr_i [256] = { 0,1,2,...255] ; and then flush all elements from cache using clflush( &arr_i[j]), but no success.

Comment: @ Mats , I have disabled other CPU core as well as ASLR , HT in CPU.

Comment: The CPUID will only guarantee that the "previous instructions are finished". It does not guarantee that future instructions aren't started. You could perhaps stick another CPUID at the backend of RDTSC, but I prefer to do a loop of operations. See edit for my code, and whilst it's not always the same results, it shows that `clflush` makes a diffference.

Comment: @ Mats, I am getting correct result for static non-const data type , (see program1 output). I am not getting correct result while I am using static const data type.

Comment: @ Mats, just checking whether I can reproduce same with const data type.  I will post my observation.

Comment: Certainly works for `const` too. Of course, if you have very few `const` values, the compiler may not "use" the values at all, but hard-code the calculated sum in the first place. `const` tells the compiler that it can be optimised into a single constant value.

Comment: I am getting result sometimes, but other times getting wrong results. Test 16650 [res=524800]
Test 16480 [res=1049600]
flush
Test 16430 [res=524800]
Test 16550 [res=1049600]

Also whenever I got lower access time after clflush, I got higher access time in 2nd access after clflsuh

Comment: That sounds a bit weird. Not sure. But why do you care at all. Flushing caches should be avoided, and the only time you should be doing it is if you need to for hardware reasons. And I don't see why measuring the timing will matter to hardware, as long as the code/hardware works, who cares what time it takes?