# How to use the output of RDTSC

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, rdtsc

My code is very simple:

```
global start
extern printf, Sleep

section .data:
    string db 'End: %llu', 0Ah, 'Start: %llu', 0

section .text:
start:
    mfence
    lfence
    rdtsc
    sub rsp, 8
    mov [rsp + 4], eax
    mov [rsp], edx
    mov rcx, 5000 ; Sleep for 5 seconds
    sub rsp, 32
    call Sleep
    add rsp, 32
    rdtscp
    pop rbx
    shl rdx, 32
    mov edx, eax
    ;RDX is end value
    ;RBX is start value
    mov r8, rbx
    mov rcx, string
    sub rsp, 40
    call printf
    add rsp, 40
    xor rax, rax
    ret
```

I am using the `RDTSC` instruction to time a piece of code (in this case the WinAPI `Sleep()` function because it makes things clearer), and the `mfence` + `lfence` pair for serialization. I ran the program 3 times and I got this output:

```
//1
End: 3717167211
Start: 12440347256463305328

//2
End: 2175818097
Start: 5820054112011561610

//3
End: 4070965503
Start: 13954488533004593819
```

From what I understand, `RDTSC` should always output increasing results, so I don't get why in test 2 the end is smaller than the start value.

Anyway, my goal is to output the amount of seconds the function actually took to execute. I would guess that I need to take the difference between the end and start values and then divide the result by the CPU frequency, but I don't know how to do that. Can anybody help?

P.S. I don't need answers about external libraries such as the CRT `clock()` as I already know how to use such functions. My point here is to learn how to use the `RDTSC` instruction.

Comment: The code only uses 32 bits of the 64-bit value it generates into edx:eax.  So overflow is quite likely when the start value is already close to 4 billion.  The actual value is not interesting, only the difference.  Use SUB.

Comment: @HansPassant Wait, I thought that in x64 `RDTSC` outputs in 64-bit RAX, not EDX:EAX. Still, what should I do with the difference?

Comment: RAX only has the low 32 bits of the 64-bit TSC (yes, even in 64-bit mode, unfortunately). Read the manual: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rdtsc.  But fortunately, the 32-bit difference still works and ignoring the high bits is fine as long as the difference is smaller enough that you don't have aliasing (missing a whole multiple of 2^32).

Comment: Also, no, you don't divide by the CPU frequency, you divide by the *reference* frequency.  This is not always exactly the same as the CPU base frequency, but e.g. on my i7-6700k it's 4008MHz while the base frequency is 4.0GHz.  And its definitely not the same as the CPU's current core clock frequency.  See also [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907627) for more details.  Also, you fenced wrong: you need `lfence; rdtsc` at the end of your timed region, or rdtscp.  (Following either of those with lfence can be useful)

Comment: I have edited the code to include the EDX:EAX and the RDTSCP but now the start value is always bigger :(

Comment: re: your edit: x86 is little-endian but you stored the low half (EAX) at a higher address (RSP+4).  That's backwards.  Also, `mov edx, eax` zero-extends EAX into RDX; use 64-bit `or` not 32-bit `mov`.  [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137)  That's why your end value is just the low half truncated.  Print in hex and it'll be easier to catch these mistakes.

Comment: Thank you! It now works. I didn't know that if you `mov edx, eax`, it fills the higher 32 bits of rdx with 0. Good to know!

Comment: See [clflush to invalidate cache line via C function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51818655) for an example of fencing RDTSC for better repeatability of measurements.  The other 3 duplicates I linked this to explain what's wrong with your current code for combining RDTSC results, and about RDTSC in general.